# Javascript Thumbnail Viewer where Images are retrieved from DB

Tags: javascript

Super Quick Break Down:
What I am attempting to do is build a Javascript Thumbnail Viewer that will display product photos, enlarged version on mouseover. 
All of my Images are coming from a sql db, retrieved via stored procedure.
Unknown number of images for each product.

I have a viewer that works awesome, when all the images are static. However, I was trying to tweak my code to get it to work for this. I have 2 main issues(that I can see):

1.) I don't think javascript is able to find the img src when I bind it the way I am.

2.) Because I am using a repeater, the id tags are not unique; therefore, javascript is unable to sort through them by Id.

Here is my code so far:

enlarged image preview goes here

```
    <img id="0" class="preview normal" src="" alt="preview" />
```

thumbnails, using a repeater (these do work but, script can't interpret)

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <img id="image1" runat="server" class="thumb normal" src='<%#: "~/Images/Catalog/" + Eval("FilePath") %>' alt="" onmouseover="preview(this)"/><br />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

Lastly, the script.

```
    <script>
                var lastImg = image1; //Set initial thumbnail and preview
                document.getElementById(0).src = document.getElementById(lastImg).src;
                document.getElementById(lastImg).className = "thumb selected";

                function preview(img) {
                    document.getElementById(lastImg).className = "thumb normal";
                    img.className = "thumb selected";
                    document.getElementById(0).src = img.src;
                    lastImg = img.id
                }
            </script>
```

I am not well versed in Javascript,just the basics, so any help with my code or at least pointing me in the right direction is appreciated. Explanations are also valued.

**Up Date**

Thanks to Sofl and a few minor tweaks I've updated the JavaScript to:

```
    function preview(img) {
                    var tar = document.getElementById('preview');
                    var thumbs = document.getElementById('thumbWrapper').children;
                    var i;

                    for (i = 0, lengthI = thumbs.length; i < lengthI; i += 1)
                        thumbs[i].className = 'thumb normal';

                    tar.src = img.src;
                    img.className = 'thumb normal';
                }
```

Mouseover on thumbnails works!

Problematic:
Unable to render an initial image on load though; because of the repeater I can not use a class(ex. Class=Active) to show which image to preview on page load(all images have the same class).

Comment: Would it be able to put together a runnable example with the hmtl generated from the repeater and javascript. The repeater code looks reasonable to me, so your problems probably lie in the javascript

Comment: The javascript is set up to identify the images by Id. Due to using a repeater, the Id's are all going to be the same(therefore, they can't be identified by Id). So yes the problem is definitely in the Javascript but, I don't know enough to even know where to begin. Also, onload the first preview isn't rendering. So I am wondering if the javascript is unable to identify my img src when it is binded like it is. Perhaps there is away to do all of this from the back and catch the images, create temporary id's and absolute paths for the Javascript to read?

Comment: If you can mock up your html on http://jsfiddle.net/ I can help with getting the javascript to work like you need.

Comment: `getElementById(0)` will not work because it expect a string. I also don't understand the point of `lastImg` so far. Anyway, I made a simple example of what I think you want to have http://jsfiddle.net/sofl/gftpk0j3/2/ jQuery version http://jsfiddle.net/sofl/xf9v06df/ jQuery version with alternate preview http://jsfiddle.net/sofl/xf9v06df/1/ . Its not an answer but could be helpful.

Comment: @sofl that is super close. It's rendering on mouse over; of course the active class creates an issue, when using the repeater (duplicating the preview and messing with the css). So I'm going to mess with it some; but, that is a massive help. Thanks so much.

Comment: Ah I got it. You can remove the class name of this image and call the preview function elsewhere (on page load for example) to set it as active. see my update: http://jsfiddle.net/gftpk0j3/4/

Comment: @Sofl You are amazing! The onload function was exactly what I needed. However, for some reason taking the class name out messed it up. So I just left all 3 class names the same, and worked like a charm. Post as an answer and I'll mark you for correct answer. Thanks again.